# Magick.NET x64 within a WCF Service - ThreadAbortException: Thead was being aborted

Tags: c#, wcf, magick.net

I have a WCF Service where i call in a certain method another methode, but with Task.StartNew(....
After that, the WCF method returns and the client loses connection.

All fine, so far.

Within this method in another thread, i use ImageMagick.NET x64 to Resize jpg images.
The last times when the service is used, i got a ThreadAbortException with the following StackTrace:

```
Message: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at Magick.Image.write(Image* , Blob* )
   at ImageMagick.MagickWriter.Write(Image* image, Blob* blob)
   at ImageMagick.MagickWriter.Write(Image* image, Stream stream)
   at My.Libs.MyService.Sync.Actions.ResizeAction.ExecuteAction(Stream sourceStream)
```

another one also showed up:

```
Message: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
at Magick.Image.resize(Image* , Geometry* )
at ImageMagick.MagickImage.Resize(MagickGeometry geometry)
at My.Libs.MyService.Sync.Actions.ResizeAction.ExecuteAction(Stream sourceStream)
```

So one time it is the Image.Resize-method, another time the Image.Write-method.

But most the time, the code is running just fine.

My question:
Is it obvious that these certain methods caused an exception which caused then a ThreadAbortException?
Or is it possible, that the expecion commes from IIS / WFF, which aborting the Operation (e.g. App Pool Recycle, Extecution timeout expired, etc.?
Wehere should i begin to investigate?

**Update**:
I StartNew without a Wait, so the call will be done very quickly, only the task is running (or should) until he hash finished, Code:

```
// Start method

Task.Factory
.StartNew(() => this.Sync(0, syncTaskStatus))
.ContinueWith(task => blSyncTaskInstance.SetFinished(syncTaskId));

// End method
```

is now...

```
Task.Factory
    .StartNew(() => this.Sync(0, syncTaskStatus), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
    .ContinueWith(task => blSyncTaskInstance.SetFinished(syncTaskId));
```

**Update Two - Code snippet where the error came and service stuff**

```
public Stream ExecuteAction(Stream sourceStream)
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    try
    {
        using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(sourceStream))
        {
            int targetWidth = this._width;
            int targetHeight = this._height;

            string geometryString;

            if (targetWidth == 0)
            {
                geometryString = "x" + targetHeight.ToString();
            }
            else if (targetHeight == 0)
            {
                geometryString = targetWidth.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    string.Format(
                        "Weder die Höhen oder, noch die Breitenangabe ist 0, was bei ResizeAction der Fall sein muss! Width: '{0}', Height: '{1}'",
                        targetWidth, targetHeight));
            }

            var resizeGeometry = new MagickGeometry(geometryString);
            image.Resize(resizeGeometry);

            // Auf Wunsch progressiv rendern.
            if (this._renderProgressive)
            {
                image.Interlace = Interlace.Line;
            }

            // Alle Bildprofile und Kommentare löschen.
            image.Strip();

            // Behebt falsche DPI Angabe mit Division durch Null in Crystal Reports.
            image.Density = new MagickGeometry(300, 300);

            image.Write(memoryStream);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        sourceStream.Dispose();

        LogService.Logger.Log(string.Format("ResizeAction failed, message: {0}", ex.Message), LogLevel.Error, ex);
        throw;
    }

    return memoryStream;
}
```

This is the code, where ExecuteAction is called:

```
private Stream GetStreamChainResult(Stream sourceStream, List<IAction> preCopyActions)
    {
        Stream workingStream = sourceStream;

        foreach (var action in preCopyActions)
        {
            workingStream = action.ExecuteAction(workingStream);
            workingStream.Position = 0;
        }

        return workingStream;
    }
```

Best Regards.

Comment: Are you using fire and forget `Task.StartNew()` or waiting for the task to finish `task.Wait()` before the WCF method returns? Try providing `StartNew` with `LongRunning` option to detach this from request thread.

Comment: Kindly post the code sample to help you better!

Comment: @cackharot See the update above. I will try with "TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning".

Comment: Post your actual service method not some isolated snippet.

Comment: Is such a thread which is created when using the flag "LongRunning" isolated from the appdomain in IIS? @Oliver Weichhold This is difficult to post and has not really more information as now. There is a Service Framework which calls a method, which calls a method, which calls the method you see above, where the important stuff happens, the Task Creation, after that, wcf call is finished and connection to client off. OK i will post the code near the program will crash and some service stuff...

Comment: Its still not clear from where `ExecuteAction` method is called. To boil down the problem, kindly replace `ExecuteAction` with `Thread.Sleep(5000)` (some seconds delay) and see Thread abort exception is occurring. If not then there is problem with `MagicImage` I suppose so test the MagicImage in a console app with multiple threads.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error on my local test environment. It occours only every 3th or 4th run on the productive system. TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning seems to be, has no effect on my problem.

Comment: I know it's been ages since you posted this but maybe you remember what the problem was?